# Scatterplot by specific date in R

Tags: r, scatter-plot

Could you help me to create a code to generate a scatter plot considering a certain date? I'm gonna explain:

I would like to make a scatter plot similar to the one I did in excel. That is, he is considering the DR sums, which is in yellow.

[image]

But as it has different dates, for example, it will be another chart, as you can see below, which I made for 02/08:

[image]

Is there any code to do this? Ie generate a scatter chart depending on date I choose?

I will inser the database below:

```
df <- structure(
  list(date = c("2021-08-01","2021-08-01","2021-08-01","2021-08-01","2021-08-01",
                "2021-08-02","2021-08-02","2021-08-02","2021-08-02","2021-08-02","2021-08-02"),
       D1 = c(0,1,0,0,5,0,1,0,0,9,4), DR01 = c(2,1,0,0,3,0,1,0,1,7,2), 
       DR02 = c(2,0,0,0,4,2,1,0,1,4,2),  DR03 = c(2,0,0,2,6,2,0,0,1,5,2),
       DR04 = c(2,0,0,5,6,2,0,0,3,7,2),  DR05 = c(2,0,0,5,6,2,0,0,7,7,2), 
       DR06 = c(2,0,0,5,7,2,0,0,7,7,1),  DR07 = c(2,0,0,6,9,2,0,0,7,8,1)), 
       class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the `tidyverse` option making use of pipes, `lubridate` and `ggplot2`.
You have a fait bit of reading to do but this will give you an example

```
df %>%
  mutate(
    date = ymd(date) #convert date field to date type (currently string)
  ) %>%
  #filter(date == ymd('2021-08-02')) %>% #decide if you want to filer or facet
  gather( "key", "value", D1:DR07) %>% #convert from wide to long
  group_by(date, key) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(value, na.rm=T)) %>% #total the figures
  ggplot(aes(x= key, y = value)) + #start of plot
    geom_point() +
    facet_grid(date ~ .) #optional - mini chart for each date - depends on how many dates you really have if loads you could do something like days ~ month etc
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! Very good and if I just want to show a graph what is it like?

Comment: That will show a graph, if you only want to see one date uncomment out the `filter` and comment `facet_grid`, that's mainly there to demo an alternative

Answer (score 1):

You may also wish to create a function that does what @Quixotic22 suggested. In this, you would specify the date in the function that will produce a scatter plot for the requested date:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
scatter_date <- function(dt, dta = df) {
    dta %>%
        mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>%
        filter(date == ymd(dt)) %>%
        summarize(across(starts_with("DR"), sum)) %>%
        pivot_longer(everything(), names_pattern = "DR(.+)", values_to = "val") %>%
        mutate(name = as.numeric(name)) %>%
        ggplot(aes(x = name, y = val)) + geom_point()
}
scatter_date("2021-08-01")
```

[image]

Comment: Mikebader, thanks for presenting another alternative :)